# Batch Renaming Relationship Classes using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, batch, relationship-class

I'm trying to rename about 100 relationship classes in a Geodatabase.
All the relationship classes are named under a naming convention and a standard part of that has changed, i.e:

abc_feature1_rel

abc_feature2_rel

**Renamed to:**

ddd_feature1_rel

ddd_feature2_rel

I would like to create a small script to automate this if possible, rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet should work for File GDB relationship classes.  Uses the [Describe object properties (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Describe_object_properties/018v00000013000000/) and the [Rename (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000056000000) tool. If your data is in SDE then you will need to account for the fully qualified names, ex. *database.schema.abc_feature1_rel*

```
import arcpy
import os

desc = arcpy.Describe(r'C:\Users\<username>\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb')

for child in desc.children:
    if child.datatype == "RelationshipClass":
        new_name = "ddd" + child.name[3:]
        arcpy.Rename_management(child.catalogpath, os.path.join(child.path, new_name))
```

I was initially having trouble listing the Relationship Classes in the GDB (there is not a "List RelationshipClasses" arcpy function) but found [this](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/57088) forum post to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses a list comprehension to rapidly generate the list of relationship classes.  The input name is then split by "_" and reconstructed to your specifications.

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r'C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'

# Generate the list of relationship classes
rc_list = [c.name for c in arcpy.Describe(workspace).children if c.datatype == "RelationshipClass"]

# Loop through the list and rename
for rc in rc_list:
    outname = "ddd" + "_" + rc.split("_")[1] + "_" + rc.split("_")[2]
    arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(workspace,rc), outname)
```