# Batch Rename Relationship Classes

Tags: arcpy, relationship-class

[Batch Renaming Relationship Classes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122553/batch-renaming-relationship-classes)

I have consulted the post above, but found that the solution is out of date and no longer works. It suggests two options to initially get the list of relationship classes:

*Option 1*

```
import arcpy
import os

desc = arcpy.Describe(r'C:\Users\<username>\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb')
print desc
for child in desc.children:
    if child.datatype == "RelationshipClass":
        print child
```

*Option 2*

```
import arcpy, os
workspace = r'C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'

# Generate the list of relationship classes
rc_list = [c.name for c in arcpy.Describe(workspace).children if c.datatype == "RelationshipClass"]
print rc_list
```

Both options returned "[]" which is an empty array. This means these are no longer viable options since I have literally 150 relationship classes to rename and none were returned.

Eventually I want to rename my relationship classes as such:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/test.gdb"


#get list of relationship classes
rc_list = [c.name for c in arcpy.Describe(env.workspace).children if c.datatype == "RelationshipClass"]  

#remove all underscores
for rc in rc_list:
    out_data = rc.replace("_","")
    arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(env.workspace,rc), out_data)

#get the list of relationship classes again
rc_list = [c.name for c in arcpy.Describe(env.workspace).children if c.datatype == "RelationshipClass"] 
for rc in rc_list:  
    #
    if "reading" in rc OR "action" in rc:
        #add underscores between name and ATTACHREL
        if "ATTACH" in rc:
            out_data = rc.replace("ATTACHREL","TblGPS__ATTACHREL")
            arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(env.workspace,rc), out_data)
            print (rc)

        #add underscores between name and rel
        if "rel" in rc:
            out_data = rc.replace("rel","TblGPS__rel")
            arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(env.workspace,rc), out_data)
            print (rc)
    else:
        #add underscores between name and ATTACHREL
        if "ATTACH" in rc:
            out_data = rc.replace("ATTACHREL","PtGPS__ATTACHREL")
            arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(env.workspace,rc), out_data)
            print (rc)

        #add underscores between name and rel
        if "rel" in rc:
            out_data = rc.replace("rel","PtGPS__rel")
            arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(env.workspace,rc), out_data)
            print (rc)
```

How can I extract the relationship classes from the geodatabase so I can rename them in bulk? I have them in a file geodatabase right now but eventually I will have them in SDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`describe (path).dataElementType` returns `DERelationshipClass` for my relationship classes.

Try this instead to be robust:

```
import arcpy
import os

desc = arcpy.Describe(r'C:\Users\<username>\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb')
print desc
for child in desc.children:
    if "RELATIONSHIPCLASS" in child.datatype.upper ():
        print child.catalogPath
```

Comment: The result: "<geoprocessing describe data object object at 0x0D04EC68>"

Comment: That’s the describe object. Do you have `print child` instead of `print child.catalogPath`?

Comment: No, I copied and pasted exactly what you wrote but changed the workspace

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your result? In my code the variable `child` will be a describe object. That is, if you print it, it will look like <geoprocessing describe data object object at 0x0D04EC68>.

Comment: Turns out my database was some how corrupted and thus, the function was not giving me the relationship classes.